# Remove entries of multiple lists with one iterator

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

I have 2 `int` Lists **A**, **B** and 1 `String` List **C**. They all have the *same* length. I want to look through C and remove all *empty* string in addition to the entries of A and B, with the same index. So for example:

```
A:[1, 2, 3]                             A:[1, 3]

B:[4, 5, 6]        should turn into     B:[4, 6]

C:["C", "", B"]                         C:["C", "B"]
```

My current code looks like this:

```
int i = 0;
for (Iterator<String> iterator = C.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String string = iterator.next();
    if (string.isEmpty()) {
        // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
        iterator.remove();
        A.remove(i);
        B.remove(i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid indices altogether and just iterate over all three lists at the same time:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
List<String> c = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a","","c"));

Iterator<Integer> a_iterator = a.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> b_iterator = b.iterator();
Iterator<String> c_iterator = c.iterator();

while (c_iterator.hasNext() && b_iterator.hasNext() && a_iterator.hasNext()){
   a_iterator.next();
   b_iterator.next();
   String cString = c_iterator.next();
   if (cString == null || cString.isEmpty()){
     a_iterator.remove();
     b_iterator.remove();
     c_iterator.remove();
   }
}
```

That said, I'd try to avoid dealing with them in separate lists at all. Trying to keep the iterators and indices straight is error prone. Instead, I would favor having a single list with a more complex object to hold the associated Integers and String:

```
public class ABC {

private final Integer a;
private final Integer b;
private final String c;

private ABC(Integer a, Integer b, String c){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

// Add Getters
```

}

Then I can just have `List<ABC>` and I always know that I have the right 'b' and 'c' associated with each 'a' and so forth. You can iterate over that list and remove the entire ABC that has a blank c. If I control the code that produces the lists, I'd skip directly to `List<ABC>`. If they're given to me like this, I'd probably still combine them, but I may just deal with them as-is if they're not used  much. In general, though, I don't like to have to write code to maintain the implied relationship between lists.

Answer (score 4):

When you remove an element by its index, the indices of all the following elements are decremented, so you have to adjust your code for that:

```
int i = 0;
for (Iterator<String> iterator = C.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String string = iterator.next();
    if (string.isEmpty()) {
        // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
        iterator.remove();
        A.remove(i);
        B.remove(i);
        // don't increment i in this case, since the former i+1'th element
        // of A and B just became the new i'th element
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```